# Convert String to Array in Presto Athena

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am new in SQL. I am trying to pass a list in WHERE IN statement. But the values are in a string similar to this:

```
'["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6"]'
```

The WHERE IN statement do not accept string but accept it:

```
WHERE IN (SELECT ids FROM unnested_id_related.id_related)
```

I can get this table using UNNEST statement

```
CROSS JOIN 
    unnest(ids) AS unnested_id_related (id_related)
```

But the value `ids`  needs to be an ARRAY. Anyone knows how can I convert String to Array? Or a better way to pass this string in the WHERE IN statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data looks like json array, so you can [parse it](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) as one and cast to array of strings:

```sql
select cast(json_parse('["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6"]') as array(varchar))
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6] |